# Get the row corresponding to the latest timestamp in a Spark Dataset using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am relatively new to Spark and Scala. I have a dataframe which has the following format:

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col_4 | Col_5 | Col_TS                  | Col_7 | 

| 1234 | AAAA | 1111 | afsdf | ewqre | 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0   | false |
| 1234 | AAAA | 1111 | ewqrw | dafda | 2017-01-17 07:09:32.748 | true  |
| 1234 | AAAA | 1111 | dafsd | afwew | 2015-01-17 07:09:32.748 | false |
| 5678 | BBBB | 2222 | afsdf | qwerq | 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0   | true  |
| 5678 | BBBB | 2222 | bafva | qweqe | 2016-12-08 07:58:43.04  | false |
| 9101 | CCCC | 3333 | caxad | fsdaa | 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0   | false |
```

What I need to do is to get the row that corresponds to the latest timestamp.
In the example above, the keys are Col1, Col2 and Col3. Col_TS represents the timestamp and Col_7 is a boolean that determines the validity of the record.
What I want to do is to find a way to group these records based on the keys and retain the one that has the latest timestamp.

So the output of the operation in the dataframe above should be:

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col_4 | Col_5 | Col_TS                  | Col_7 | 

| 1234 | AAAA | 1111 | ewqrw | dafda | 2017-01-17 07:09:32.748 | true  |
| 5678 | BBBB | 2222 | bafva | qweqe | 2016-12-08 07:58:43.04  | false |
| 9101 | CCCC | 3333 | caxad | fsdaa | 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0   | false |
```

I came up with a partial solution but this way I can only return the dataframe of the Column keys on which the records are grouped and not the other columns.

```
df = df.groupBy("Col1","Col2","Col3").agg(max("Col_TS"))


| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | max(Col_TS)             |

| 1234 | AAAA | 1111 | 2017-01-17 07:09:32.748 |
| 5678 | BBBB | 2222 | 2016-12-08 07:58:43.04  | 
| 9101 | CCCC | 3333 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0   |
```

Can someone help me in coming up with a Scala code for performing this operation?

Answer (score 18):

You can use `window` function as following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Col1","Col2","Col3").orderBy(col("Col_TS").desc)

df.withColumn("maxTS", first("Col_TS").over(windowSpec))
.select("*").where(col("maxTS") === col("Col_TS"))
.drop("maxTS")
  .show(false)
```

You should get output as following

```
+----+----+----+-----+-----+----------------------+-----+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col_4|Col_5|Col_TS                |Col_7|
+----+----+----+-----+-----+----------------------+-----+
|5678|BBBB|2222|bafva|qweqe|2016-12-0807:58:43.04 |false|
|1234|AAAA|1111|ewqrw|dafda|2017-01-1707:09:32.748|true |
|9101|CCCC|3333|caxad|fsdaa|1970-01-0100:00:00.0  |false|
+----+----+----+-----+-----+----------------------+-----+
```

Comment: is `select("*")` necessary here ?

Answer (score 2):

One option is firstly order the data frame by *Col_TS*, then group by *Col1*, *Col2* and *Col3* and take the last item from each other column:

```
val val_columns = Seq("Col_4", "Col_5", "Col_TS", "Col_7").map(x => last(col(x)).alias(x))

(df.orderBy("Col_TS")
   .groupBy("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")
   .agg(val_columns.head, val_columns.tail: _*).show)

+----+----+----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col_4|Col_5|              Col_TS|Col_7|
+----+----+----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+
|1234|AAAA|1111|ewqrw|dafda|2017-01-17 07:09:...| true|
|9101|CCCC|3333|caxad|fsdaa|1970-01-01 00:00:...|false|
|5678|BBBB|2222|bafva|qweqe|2016-12-08 07:58:...|false|
+----+----+----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Psidom. I got the overall idea but could you describe what does the `agg(val_columns.head, val_columns.tail: _*)` part do?

Comment: The `val_columns` is a Seq of aggregation expressions, `agg(val_columns.head, val_columns.tail: _*)` apply each element in `val_columns` as a separate parameter to `agg` function which is equivalent to `agg(last(col("Col_4")).alias("Col_4"), last(col("Col_5")).alias("Col_5"), ... etc`, but just shorter and more programmatic.

Comment: Excellent! And so concise. Thank you.

Comment: is there a garantee that groupBy retains the ordering? I don't think so..

Comment: I think you're right. Group by does not retain the ordering. @Psidom  Is there a way of making sure that the order is maintained?