# Get latest records from cassandra table by spark using java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have found this answer [Get the row corresponding to the latest timestamp in a Spark Dataset using Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450131/get-the-row-corresponding-to-the-latest-timestamp-in-a-spark-dataset-using-scala)

"edate" is of  date datatype.

I want the similar output using java.
I tried this:

```
java.sql.Date yesterdayDate = yesterday();  
    Dataset<Row> wds = wddt.where(wddt.col("c").equalTo(yesterdayDate)).groupBy("mobileno").max("edate");
```

but I am getting this error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: "edate" is not a numeric column. Aggregation function can only be applied on a numeric column.;
at org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset$$anonfun$3.apply(RelationalGroupedDataset.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset$$anonfun$3.apply(RelationalGroupedDataset.scala:98)
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from the error message and the naming, "edate" seems to be a date column and not a numeric column. Thats why you get this error message.

see also [how to get max(date) from given set of data grouped by some fields using pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377894/how-to-get-maxdate-from-given-set-of-data-grouped-by-some-fields-using-pyspark)

Comment: yes, it is a date column. I want to get the latest record based on edate

Comment: so have you tried the solution given in the answer I linked? .agg(max_("edate")))

Comment: Yes, 

I am getting an error max(String) is not defined and after that I create a blank method
`private Map<String, String> max(String string) {
        return null;
    }` 
Help me for the logic which is required under this?